# Android Google Cloud Messaging registration ID expired after 24 hours

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I recently began working with Google Cloud Messaging for push notifications. I have an app that I have not released a signed apk for (information provided in case there is some detection of dev builds) and have not reinstalled the app in any way shape or form.

My app requests a registration ID, I store it manually while the server side is being worked on, and test with a small bit of code on the server that is set up to send push notifications. It works for the bulk of the day but the following morning I get a response "{ error: 'NotRegistered' }".

I have taken no actions to unregister the device and the app version has not changed.

[edit] Added relevant bits from Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<!-- Stuff for push notifications -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<permission android:name="com.my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<!-- end push notifications stuff -->


    public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    /**
     * Check for Google Play Services APK
     */
    if(myApp.checkPlayServices(this)){
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        regid = getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext());

        if( regid == null || regid.isEmpty() || (myApp.getSP().getInt(Constants.PROPERTY_APP_VERSION,-1) <= getAppVersion(this)) ){
            registerInBackground();
        } else {
            L.i("Using GCM ID:" + regid);
        }
    } else {
        L.i("No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
    }

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE");
    gcmReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                String[] params = {extras.getString("imgUrl"), gcm.getMessageType(intent), extras.toString()};
                new GCMReceiverTask().execute(params);
        }
    };
    this.registerReceiver(gcmReceiver,intentFilter);
}

/**
 * Stuff pertaining to push notifications
 */

String SENDER_ID = null;
String regid = null;
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;

/**
 * Gets the current registration ID for application on GCM service.
 * <p>
 * If result is empty, the app needs to register.
 *
 * @return registration ID, or empty string if there is no existing
 *         registration ID.
 */
private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = myApp.getSP();
    String registrationId = prefs.getString(Constants.PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
    if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
        L.i("Registration not found.");
        return "";
    }
    // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
    // since the existing registration ID is not guaranteed to work with
    // the new app version.
    int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(Constants.PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
    if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
        L.i("App version changed.");
        return "";
    }
    return registrationId;
}

/**
 * @return Application's version code from the {@code PackageManager}.
 */
private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        return packageInfo.versionCode;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        // should never happen
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
    }
}

/**
 * Registers the application with GCM servers asynchronously.
 * <p>
 * Stores the registration ID and app versionCode in the application's
 * shared preferences.
 */
private void registerInBackground() {
    new GCMRegistrationTask().execute(null, null, null);
}

/**
 * Sends the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it can use GCM/HTTP
 * or CCS to send messages to your app. Not needed for this demo since the
 * device sends upstream messages to a server that echoes back the message
 * using the 'from' address in the message.
 */
private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
    // Your implementation here.
    L.i("WOULD SEND REGISTRATION TO SERVER... " + regid);
}

/**
 * Stores the registration ID and app versionCode in the application's
 * {@code SharedPreferences}.
 *
 * @param regId registration ID
 */
private void storeRegistrationId(String regId) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = myApp.getSP();
    int appVersion = getAppVersion(this);
    L.i("Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(Constants.PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
    editor.putInt(Constants.PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
    editor.commit();
}

/**
 * Unregisters the application with GCM servers asynchronously.
 * <p>
 * Removes the registration ID and app versionCode from the application's
 * shared preferences.
 */
private void unRegisterInBackground() {
    new GCMRegistrationTask(true).execute(null, null, null);
}

private class GCMReceiverTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Expect params[0] to be image URL, params[1] to be messageType
        String imageUrl = params[0];

        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(Main.this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = params[1];

        // Stringified extras as last param
        String extrasString = params[params.length - 1];

        /*
         * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
         * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
         * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
         * recognize.
         */
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            L.e("Send error: " + extrasString);
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            L.i("Deleted messages on server: " +
                    extrasString);
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            // retrieve image
            try {
                L.i("Got image URL: " + imageUrl);
                String[] parts = imageUrl.split("/");
                String fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];
                if (imageUrl.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new Exception("No Image URL supplied.");
                }
                ServerCall sc = new ServerCall(imageUrl, ServerCall.POST);
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + getPackageName().toString() + File.separator + "user_images";
                sc.saveByteArrayToLocalFile(path, fileName);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                L.e("ERROR writing image to storage: " + Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
            // Post notification of received message.
            L.i("Received: " + extrasString);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String msg){
        Button proceed = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        if( proceed != null ){
            proceed.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}

private class GCMRegistrationTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private boolean unregistering = false;
    GCMRegistrationTask() {
        this(false);
    }
    GCMRegistrationTask(boolean unregister) {
        super();
        this.unregistering = unregister;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String msg = "";
        try {
            if (gcm == null) {
                gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            }
            if( unregistering ) {
                gcm.unregister();

                myApp.getSP()
                        .edit()
                        .remove(Constants.PROPERTY_REG_ID)
                        .commit();

            } else {
                SENDER_ID = myApp.getSP().getString(Constants.GCM_SENDER_ID,null);
                if( SENDER_ID != null ) {
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                    // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
                    // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                    // The request to your server should be authenticated if your app
                    // is using accounts.
                    sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                    // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
                    // will send upstream messages to a server that echo back the
                    // message using the 'from' address in the message.

                    // Persist the registration ID - no need to register again.
                    storeRegistrationId(regid);
                } else {
                    L.e("SHOULD NOT GET HERE, GCM_SENDER_ID SHOULD NOT BE NULL! " + myApp.getSP().getString(Constants.GCM_SENDER_ID,"[[EMPTY]]"));
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
            // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
            // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
            // exponential back-off.
        }
        return msg;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
        // handle postExecute - Nothing to do?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is intentional.

Registration IDs will expire after some time. Client should detect that and request another ID.

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

`As stated above, an Android app must register with GCM servers and get a registration ID before it can receive messages. A given registration ID is not guaranteed to last indefinitely, so the first thing your app should always do is check to make sure it has a valid registration ID (as shown in the code snippets above).`

Comment: According to the documentation it should only be invalidated when the app is uninstalled or upgraded. That is definitely not the case here. The code I have in my question is directly based upon the code referenced at the URL you provided. Further, there is nothing there about the client checking that it's registration id is still valid with the GCM servers, it checks to see if the app version has updated, which my code does as well.

Comment: RegistrationID is a security token so it must have expiration. Also, previous google push notification API registration tokens had expiration. Believe me or not, but that is probably error or misunderstanding of documentation.

Comment: @user1445898, you're saying it's the expected behavior for it to expire in 24 hours?